# What is this broken part/fuse?

Tags: identification, connector, passive-components, component-failure, power-connector

This is a part that has been corroded from water contact. I appears to be a small connector with a ceramic base and two spade terminals. The wiring diagram for the item it's from identifies it as a fuse, but it cannot be purchased separately.

The body of the connector as shown below is 17mm wide, and there should be a spade terminal coming off to the left and right from the main body.

[image: Damaged connector]

On the back side, I found the following numbers that may or may not be part numbers. I've had no luck finding the part online.

```
155 131 003
23       16
260C
```

Any help identifying this part and a place where I can buy it would be appreciated. Thank you!

If it's any help identifying the part, it's from an LG dishwasher.

Comment: It looks similar to this: https://www.amresupply.com/part/13094097 a 260 °C over temperature limit breaker. Question is, is it really just corroded or was there a different fault which led to this. And you still need to find the correct part...

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Exchange is not for repairs. Try https://old.reddit.com/r/appliancerepair/

Comment: @DavideAndrea: Would it be in-bounds to re-ask this as a component identification question without the repair context? Thanks.

Comment: @DavideAndrea it's a bit strange, if all the repair stuff would have been excluded and just the broken part would've been shown with a question to identify it, then it probably wouldn't have been closed - we have dozens of identify this broken component questions.

Comment: @Arsenal: That seems like a possibility. I'll see if I can't run it down based on that clue. I was wondering if 260C was some kind of rating. Thank you!

Comment: that's burnt, not corroded, plastic doesn't corrode.

Comment: @dandavis True in this particular case, but we can speak of corrosion wrt plastics. For example, [stress corrosion cracking failures].